# YouCompleteMe vim extension: How to jump to next error?

Tags: ide, vim

Is there any way when using the YouCompleteMe vim extension to jump to the next point in the file with an error? I find myself just scrolling through the page until I find the error highlight, but there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you `let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1`, YouCompleteMe will populate vims location list with new diagnostic data. You can jump through the entries in that list with `:lnext` and `:lprevious`. You can read more about the location list in the documentation of the quickfix feature (`:h location-list` or [use the online version](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html)).

Comment: (also, for others, `:ln` and `:lp` for short!) :D

Comment: `:ln` is not mapped afaik, it should be `:lne`. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html

Comment: @badbishop Please open a new question in U&L or https://vi.stackexchange.com/ with the exact steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The issue was actually that :lnext wouldn't move cursor if there's a single error, but with :ll it works.